# How to display image except for one item on Foreach loop in swiftUI?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

I've created an card and I want an image to display on top of each card except for the first one. please help me to solve this.

This is the struct that holds the image.

```
struct XButton: View {
var body: some View {
    Image(systemName: "xmark")
            .font(.system(size: 17, weight: .bold))
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .padding(.all, 10)
            .background(Color.black.opacity(0.6))
            .mask(Circle())
        }
}
```

This the scrollview that contains the cards inside the foreach loop

```
ScrollView{
                    ForEach(CardsData) { item in
                    VStack {
                        
                        CardsView(Cards: item)

                          }
                }
          }
```

Comment: So you want Button to appear on top of all `CardsView`s except the first, correct?

Comment: yeah, exactly!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `enumerated()` to get the index *and* item during a `ForEach`. Then, `XButton` is only rendered conditionally if `index == 0`

Then, I use `ZStack` to put the `XButton` on top. I'm assuming "on top" in your original question means overlaid, but if you just meant higher on the y axis, you could change this back to a `VStack`

```
struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView{
            ForEach(Array(CardsData.enumerated()), id: \.1.id) { (index,item) in
                ZStack {
                    CardsView(Cards: item)
                    if index == 0 {
                        XButton()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note: this is assuming that `CardsData` items conform to `Identifiable`, which I assume they did if your original `ForEach` worked. Note that I'm getting the id from `.1.id` which is the `id` property of the item in the `CardsData` which is now a tuple where the first part (0) is the index and the second (1) is the item.